# OneNote App Version - Custom Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

I use the OneNote App for Windows 8.1 (App version, not desktop/office version). I like to use many symbols (→, etc.) in my notes, but it is hard to add them. Does anyone know how I can add custom keyboard shortcuts to do this?

For example:
[CTRL + right arrow]  to get →

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts in OneNote aren't customizable in way you expect. However, you can create similar effect using free open source tool [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org). Either [remap your keyboard](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) or use [hotstrings](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm) (or combine both ways) to achieve what you need.

For example, right arrow you can produce by typing `rarr` (and space) after you added the following hotstring definition:

```
::rarr::→
```

But think twice about remapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> because it is already widely used. Hotstrings are suitable much more for the task.